# Netbeans 7.0.1 > How to get Java as first file type when New File.. 

Tags: netbeans

How to get Java as first file type when New File.. in Netbeans 7.0.1

It's always Java Card™ 3 Platform.

I've looked around in the menus, but is this possible to tweak?